# Calling setter from JSF page which was declared with different parameter from variable itself

Tags: jsf, el, setter, converters

I'm using an External lib which has many classes with variables declared like that:

```
private String testBigDecimal;

public String getTestBigDecimal() {
    return this.testBigDecimal;
}

public void setTestBigDecimal(BigDecimal testBigDecimal) {
    this.testBigDecimal = BigDecimalValidador.validationXpto( testBigDecimal); //return String
}
```

Note that setter() method receives a BigDecimal value due to some validation process and return a String value. When those are called from server side everything is OK! ...but when called from view side (JSF page) with proper BigDecimalConverter I'm getting this Error:

> javax.faces.component.UpdateModelException: javax.el.PropertyNotWritableException: ... Property [testBigDecimal] not writable on type ....

After Converter is correctly invoked, the code fails because it is still expecting for a `setTestBigDecimal(Srting testBigDecimal)` metohd.

My JSF Page:   `<h:inputText value="#{fooBean.testBigDecimal}"      converter="bigDecimalConverter"   />`

Is there a way to ensure JSF can call the declared setter (which was in a "non standard way")? 
In a local tests I changed 'String testBigDecimal'  to  'BigDecimal testBigDecimal' type and everything works fine, but I can't change the Lib Source and Extend all this classes will be painful.

Anyone can help?

Comment: I don't think you can access a property without its getter and setter in "non standard way".  You can create setter for `testBigDecimal` and use `valueChangeListener` to access the changed value and apply your logic on the bean to achieve what you are desiring.

Comment: Thank you @Noah, In fact I ended creating a new ordinary class with all standard get/set that hold this 'from-to' for library class =/. Would be nice if JSF also could look for an existence of a setter with parameters declared with the same type of the explicitly value returned from it's conversion class (rather than only search for the same getter type).

Comment: JSF relies on the EL spec. EL spec relies on the JavaBeans spec. JavaBeans spec says: `If we discover a matching pair of “get<PropertyName>” and “set<PropertyName>” methods that take and return the same type, then we regard these methods as defining a read-write property whose name will be “<propertyName>”` - so the same type is inherent to the definition of a property. JSF is right to follow the specs, they're there to ensure interoperability. Maybe your external lib should follow JavaBeans. Or maybe you shouldn't expect some external lib to follow JavaBeans and provide your own wrappers.